# Parse.com - Who sets updatedAt and createdAt properties?

Tags: parse-platform

Title is pretty much the question, when `PFObject` is created what values are stored in `updatedAt` and `createdAt` properties? Are those values from local device time or they are world time and 100% correct.

I need somehow to store a current world date, without letting user to trick my app by switching the date in setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Parse.com** set it for you in order to let you keep track of the created date and updated date. Time zone is PST so that when you should set PST as your time zone from your time handler object and it will offset it for you automatically.

EDIT: I have this experience before when I was working with my Indian coworkers. The default time zone GMT and it will not work unless Parse.com returns GMT time zone. So, we have to set PST as time zone in our time handler object and it will offset properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider those values are set / updated by parse when data hits the server and treat them as almost private as you don't have direct control. If you need to protect some information then you should use cloud code to update it and set appropriate ACLs to prevent access to it from other routes.